# hadoop hdfs directory size shown as 0

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Every time I use ***hadoop fs -ls /path_to_directory*** or  ***hadoop fs -ls -h /path_to_directory*** , the result is like the following

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-08-05 00:22/user/hive-0.13.1/warehouse/t_b_city
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-06-15 16:28/user/hive-0.13.1/warehouse/t_b_mobile
```

The size of directory inside HDFS is always shown as 0 no matter there is file wihin it or not.

Browsing from the web UI gives the same reuslt as following :

```
drwxr-xr-x  hadoop  supergroup  0 B 0   0 B t_b_city
drwxr-xr-x  hadoop  supergroup  0 B 0   0 B t_b_mobile
```

However, there are actually files within those directory. When using command ***hadoop fs -du  -h /user/hive-0.13.1/warehouse/*** , the directory size can be shown correctly as the following:

```
385.5 K   /user/hive-0.13.1/warehouse/t_b_city
1.1 M     /user/hive-0.13.1/warehouse/t_b_mobile
```

Why would the ***hadoop fs -ls*** command of hdfs and the web UI always show 0 for a directory ?

Also, the ***hadoop fs -ls*** command usually finish immediately while the  ***hadoop fs -du*** would take sometime to execute. It seems that the ***hadoop fs -ls*** command doesn't actually spend time on calculating total size of a directory.

Comment: When you run a `ls -l` command on Linux, the "size" displayed for directories is not related to the size of the files inside. So why did you expect HDFS to work differently???

Comment: BTW, the NameNode stores the whole filesystem information in RAM and not on disk, therefore a directory entry requires zero bytes on disk. On the other hand Linux filesystems require a few disk segments to persist each directory *(list of `inodes`, permissions etc)*

Comment: Thanks. Seems my understanding for the ls command have long been wrong. I took it for granted that ls will show size for both file and directory.

Comment: Again, the size of a directory is the size of the **directory object**. Just like the size of a file is the size of a file. Full stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working as designed. Hadoop is designed for big files and one should not expect it to give the size of each and every time one run `hadoop fs -ls` command. If Hadoop works in way you want then try to think from another person point of view who might just want to see whether directory exists or not; but end up waiting long time just because Hadoop is calculating size of folder; not so good.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense and  I rechecked the description for -ls command at [link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls). The description only say the command will give size for a file but not directory.

Answer (score 1):

> try to do the wild card with the du option so that all the files under
>   a db are listed with the file sizes. The only catch here is that we
>   need to go for multiple levels of wilcard pattern match so that all
>   the levels under the parent directory is covered.

```
hadoop fs -du -h /hive_warehouse/db/*/* > /home/list_du.txt
```