# Pyspark 3.3.0 dataframe show data but writing CSV creates empty file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

Facing a very unusual issue. Dataframe shows data if ran `df.show()` however, when trying to write as csv, operation completes without error , but writes 0 byte empty file.

Is this a bug ? Is there something missing?

--pyspark version

```
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.15, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_352
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user ubuntu on 2022-06-09T19:58:58Z
Revision f74867bddfbcdd4d08076db36851e88b15e66556
Url https://github.com/apache/spark
```

--Python Version

```
Python 3.9.13 (main, Aug 25 2022, 23:26:10)
[GCC 11.2.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

--dataframe shows data if fetched

```
>>> result.show()
+--------------------+
|     review_keywords|
+--------------------+
|        [love, echo]|
|         [loved, it]|
|[sometimes, playi...|
|[lot, fun, thing,...|
|             [music]|
|[received, echo, ...|
|[without, cellpho...|
|[think, 5th, one,...|
|      [looks, great]|
|[love, it, i’ve, ...|
|[sent, 85, year, ...|
|[love, it, learni...|
|[purchased, mothe...|
|[love, love, love, ]|
|          [expected]|
|[love, it, wife, ...|
|[really, happy, p...|
|[using, alexa, co...|
|[love, size, 2nd,...|
|[liked, original,...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

--however write operation creates 0 byte empty file

```
>>> result.withColumn('review_keywords', col('review_keywords').cast('string')).write.option("header", "true").mode('overwrite').csv("hdfs:///tmp/some_dir/some_other_dir/word_tokens.txt")
```

--hdfs file gets created but 0 byte

```
$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs:///tmp/some_dir/some_other_dir/
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - xyz supergroup          0 2023-03-30 09:18 hdfs:///tmp/some_dir/some_other_dir/word_tokens.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Spark really does when doing `df.write.csv` is writing away a *directory*, not a *file*. As is discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953101/hadoop-hdfs-directory-size-shown-as-0), `hadoop fs -ls` displays directory disk usage as 0.

If you're interested in the size of the file you've just written, try using `hadoop fs -dus hdfs:///tmp/some_dir/some_other_dir/word_tokens.txt`. More info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574410/how-to-find-the-size-of-a-hdfs-file).

Comment: I feel really stupid now!! Classic example why not paying attention to details in documentation can do! 
Thank you for answering with patience Sir! XD @Koedlt

P.S : However, it seems doc also mentions `path` can be single csv. I guess it was misleading https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html

Comment: Haha no worries, I've been very guilty of not reading documentation well in the past :) Good luck for the rest!

Comment: By the way those docs talk about *reading* in a file: that can be a single CSV indeed. Writing a CSV will always write a directory :)

Comment: But you can use `repartition(0)` to force it to a single file within a directory